# Spring Webflux: Read request-body in ServerWebExchangeMatcher

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-webflux

I have to create an application with just **one** endpoint where users can log in and do their other operational stuff. Users should be able to log in with a request body like:

{
"login": {
"token": "12345"
}
}

So every request with a body like this should be allowed via .permitAll() by the WebFilterChain.
The chain is configured like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain chain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> {
                exchanges.matchers(new LoginRequestMatcher())
                        .permitAll()
                        .pathMatchers("api/v1*")
                        .hasRole("USER");
            })
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .build();
}
```

The **LoginRequestMatcher** analyzes the body of the request and returns a Match if the pattern is ok. So far, this works quite fine.

My problem is that later in the Controller, **the request body can not be accessed any more**, so I'm currently trying to put it into a cache or the context to be able to access it later on.

Here is my current implementation of the LoginRequestMatcher:

```
public class LoginRequestMatcher implements ServerWebExchangeMatcher {

private static final Pattern loginRequestPattern = Pattern.compile("...loginPattern");

@Override
public Mono<MatchResult> matches(final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getRequest().getBody()
            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] byteArray=new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(byteArray);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                return byteArray;
            }).defaultIfEmpty(new byte[0])
            .map(bytes -> {
                        ServerHttpRequestDecorator decorator = initDecorator(exchange, bytes);
                        exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build();
                        Mono.just(decorator).contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("decorator",decorator))
                        return decorator;
                    }
            )
          // Rest of the code checks for Regex in the body and works fine.
            .next();
```

Now, when I try to get the cached request-body after the RequestMatcher is processed (f.e. in a WebFilter), the context does not contain an object with the key "decorator".

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
public class HttpRequestBodyCachingFilter implements WebFilter {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain) {

    final HttpMethod method = exchange.getRequest().getMethod();
    // Nothing to cache for GET and DELETE
    if (method==null || HttpMethod.GET==method || HttpMethod.DELETE==method) {
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    // Get decorator from context

    return Mono.just(exchange)
            //ctx.get("decorator") throws Exception here, because the key does not exist.
            .flatMap(s -> Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> ctx.get("decorator")))
            .map(decorator ->
                (ServerHttpRequestDecorator) decorator)
            .flatMap(decorator -> chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(decorator).build()));

}
}
```

How can I make the body readable after accessing it in inside a ServerWebExchangeMatcher?